# How I can know if the user cancel the subscription or not?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I have implemented IAP in my flutter app successfully! My problem is how do I know if the user cancels the subscription or not?

I have tried:
await FlutterInappPurchase.checkSubscribed();

But it's always returning "false"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Real time developer notifications. It uses Google PubSub that sends the information to your endpoint as and when the subscriptions update or get cancelled. It is easily configurable in the Play Store Console.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Handle-states

Comment: This would have been great! But it seems to me there is no way to get the auth information of the user associated with the subscription. @Samarth Agarwal, is there a way to get that Auth Context? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference#sub

Answer (score 1):

You can use `await InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases();` to restore current purchases. Once the user cancels or pauses his subscriptions, the product will no longer appear in the restored products list.

This is exactly what I have done.

```
 final purchasedUpdated = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;
    StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _subscription = purchasedUpdated.listen(_onPurchasedUpdated);
await InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases();
```

And later,

```
     void _onPurchasedUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((purchaseDetails){
if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
      print(purchaseDetails.productID);
    }
});
  }
```

The subscription stream will listen to updates on subscriptions in the app.

Comment: I did the same thing as you did, but even after I cleared purchase history at the "Sandbox Testers" section on App Store Connect, and cancelled the subscription at the SandBox account-> Manage on my iPhone I still received transactions with the status PurchaseStatus.restored.
Any idea why?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? i am having the same issue.